# Issue on SMTP access via Internet

Tags: email, smtp, lotus-domino

Currently we are implementing to use POP3 / IMAP service for flexibility of mail clients.
We are also overlooking on mobiles to be able to access via internet.

We have successfully configured the POP3 / IMAP service and tested already.
Now, the main issue when connecting to the SMTP server. I am planning to 
publicly publish an open STMP relay but with user authentication.

Mail Client (e.g. IMAP) --> Internet --> Firewall ---> Email Server (Relay Host to) --> Microsoft Exchange Online Protection --> External Domain

Right now I was able to test the SMTP service using telnet domain.com 25 it was successfully and having reply from ehlo / helo command.
But via on the internet the command or connection reply only with *************** or unrecognized command.

We have already disable SMPT checking or fixup on firewall equipment still no good. 
I am thinking to use the Microsoft Exchange Online Protection as alternative relay agent.

But how do I configure the Microsoft EOP and mail client on this? Or can you recommend alternative solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Why not use Traveler for mobile access? And to be flexible in the means of Mail client: Ask your IBM Sales Rep for "IBM Mail Support for Microsoft Outlook" (aka Hawthorn)...

Comment: IBM Traveler is not free..when using via internet it must be purchased then. Regarding IBM Mail Support for Microsoft Outlook it is already working and tested on internal network only. We are looking on using via internet and mobile.

Comment: IBM Traveler IS FREE! Whoever told you, that it isn't is lying...

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions about programming.  Is there a programming question here?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong..I was thinking MyNotes..do you have any links for IBM Traveler configuration or setup?

Comment: @DaveDelay My bad..I was rushing on posting the question, I thought this would be Serverfault.com..can this be transfered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traveler should be included with your Lotus Domino license.

Comment: I cannot locate IBM Traveler for Lotus Domino 8.5.3..and another problem it doesn't support Windows Server 2012 as OS.

Comment: Have you checked passport advantage?